# Why is the user automatically logged out after 60 minutes, using cookie authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, session-cookies, asp.net-core-3.1, blazor-webassembly

We have an Blazor WASM app and want to authenticate an user by Cookie-Authentication. The Problem:
We want to keep the login for 30 days, but the user logs out after 60 minutes. We have tried multiple configurations which are posted on stackoverflow with no success.

**Startup.cs (Server Side)**

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie(options =>
{
    // [...]
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = System.TimeSpan.FromDays(30); // 30 Days
});

// [...]

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    // [...]

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    // [...]
}
```

**MyController.cs (Server Side)**

```
public async Task<AuthResponse> Login(Credentials pCredentials)
{
    // [...]
    
    // set cookie
    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
    CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
    new ClaimsPrincipal(lClaimsIdentity),
    new AuthenticationProperties
    {
        IsPersistent = true,
        ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(30), // 30 Days
        RedirectUri = this.Request.Host.Value
    });

    // [...]
}
```

Advanced settings of the application pool (IIS):

[image: application pool configuration]

**Hint:** We use the `[Authorize]`-Attribute to restrict controllers. When we make an request to any restricted controller after 60 minutes, then we get an http-status code 401. But in the browser, the auth-cookie still exists:

[image: authentication cookie]

Question: Why is the user logged out after 60 minutes?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this issue has to do with your application being inactive and shutting down. This means that when the application starts up again it's going to generate new keys for creating the cookie. You can test this by restarting your app and see if user get's logged out.

I recommend to persist keys to file system with something like:

```
services.AddDataProtection()
   .SetApplicationName("IdentityServer")
   .PersistKeysToFileSystem(MyKeyPath);
```

which means authentication sessions will survive server restarts as well.

Comment: Where can you see in my post that my "application being inactive and shutting down"?

Answer (score 0):

In the IIS-Manager (inetmgr), Go to "Application Pools" > "Advanced Settings":

Set the Idle-Timeout in IIS to 0 and recylce the application pool.

[image: IIS Idle Time-out]

A day later, the user is still logged in as expected.